# Changing looks of text in a dialog

Tags: android, layout

I have created dialogs in my app using java only. I wanted to ask how can I adjust the size of text in the dialog message using java code. Also, I want to make the text in it look justified (means leaving no blank spaces on the either side).
My code sample is as follows:

```
if (v == findViewById(R.id.button1)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                    .setTitle("Paracettamol")
                    .setMessage(
                            "This medicine is generally used to cure Fever")
                    .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
```

Also, how can I underline or make it look italic or bold. The tags like  do not work here.

Comment: Yes, i know that its paracetamol and it supresses fever, i wrote it jus to see if the code works.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to cast a vote and what does it really mean.

Comment: see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up)

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own `TextView` with wanted text size, color, or anything else. And use `Builder.setView(View)` instead of `Builder.setMessage(String)`.

Comment: +1 exactly, this way you can create a custom dialog, in short define a layout and set it to dialog by using setView(view) method.